# Execute Dispose only if variable is zero

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

Rough context: messaging system, `Communicator` sends messages (increases field `_messagesInTransmission`), receives ACK or NAK on another thread (decreases `_messagesInTransmission`).

If an instance of Communicator is disposed it should stop its underlying transport instance as soon as `_messagesInTransmission` hits zero the next time.

How to implement this in a thread-safe way?

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _state = State.Stopping; // immediately change state in order to prevent additional messages to be sent

    // TODO: wait for _messagesInTransmission to become zero
}
```

Does the .NET framework support me with this task?

---

A simple solution would be a while(_mIT != 0) loop and some Thread.Sleep, however, I want to write more appealing code if possible.

Comment: Is the message transmission taking place in another thread?

Comment: Most probably, I'm using a framework based on Microsoft CCR under the hood.

Comment: Keep in mind that the guidelines for implementing `IDisposable` states that multiple calls to `Dispose` should be allowed on the same object.

Comment: @Brian: Thanks, I'm now checking for the current `_state` in the beginning! -> I hope Dispose does not need to be thread-safe? (in my case, of course not, however, I don't know about the C# language recommendation)

Answer (score 3):

You really don't want to do this on `Dispose()`.

Consider a situation where your receiving application crashes and never ACK/NACK's one of the messages. You'll never receive enough responses to zero the counter, and when the dispose is called, possibly during GC or a `using(...){...}` block, it's going to hang indefinitely.

I'd suggest moving this functionality to another method which is called `OnStop()`.

And just keep your `Dispose()` method for cleaning up resources, closing connections etc...

Comment: I'm thinking of a timeout to prevent indefinite hanging, in case the timeout is reached I can log an error.

Answer (score 1):

How vital is it that those messages are sent? Generally, you should have some kind of `Stop()` method on your class to do what you are looking for. Doing this kind of action in the Dispose method is a little dangerous because Dispose methods shouldn't have the potential to throw errors or hang.

Also, make sure your worker thread is created with `IsBackground` set to true. That way, when your application closes, it is certain to complete as well.

Answer (score 1):

The "thread safe" way to do it (and is how things like `FileStream` handle it) is to have a `Flush()` method that is blocking that writes out all the pending writes. Once you have that you just need to have `Flush()` be called inside the `Dispose()` method.

Now this will cause `Dispose()` to block, but you know what? We want dispose to block! If you do not block on dispose while work is still being done the last reference to the object could be released (very likely to happen inside a `using` block) and your object will be eligible for garbage collection before it is done processing.